# AngularJS date in ng-model value not pass to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

when i click  CheckAvailability button date value doesnot pass to controller

```
<div class='input-group date'>
         <input ng-model="BookedFromDate" type="text" value=@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") class="form-control BookedFDate" style="border-width: 0 0 2px 0;">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="font-icon font-icon-calend"></i>
       </span>
                                       
   </div>
```

Anguler:

```
$scope.CheckAvailability = function () {
    alert("Hello, " + $scope.BookedFromDate);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget ASP. In AngularJS input doesn't need a value. Simply populate the `ng-model`. You can do it in controller or with `ng-init` in HTML. To mask/filter the date, use `$filter` service. It's usually not used directly, so I suggest applying a filter in `ng-init`. AngularJS has a `date` filter for this purpose.

Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.now = new Date();
  $scope.CheckAvailability = function() {
    console.log("Date:", $scope.BookedFromDate);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class='input-group date'>
      <input ng-model="BookedFromDate" 
             type="text" 
             ng-init="BookedFromDate = (now | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy')" 
             class="form-control BookedFDate" 
             style="border-width: 0 0 2px 0;">

      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="font-icon font-icon-calend"></i>
    </span>
      <button ng-click="CheckAvailability()">Click</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Alternatively change the type from `text`  to `date` to completely ignore the filter and masking.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.BookedFromDate = new Date();
  $scope.CheckAvailability = function() {
    console.log("Date:", $scope.BookedFromDate);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class='input-group date'>
      <input ng-model="BookedFromDate" 
             type="date" 
             class="form-control BookedFDate" 
             style="border-width: 0 0 2px 0;">

      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="font-icon font-icon-calend"></i>
    </span>
      <button ng-click="CheckAvailability()">Click</button>

    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir one more doubt `<input type='text' class="form-control" name="FromTime" ng-model="FromTime" placeholder="From Time" />` time value how to pass

Comment: @IvinRaj it's bound to your model, so access it with `$scope.FromTime = ...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930827/angularjs-time-in-ng-model-value-not-pass-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps, in angular, **value** tag is of less use as we are binding the values 2-way.

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="EditCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.title" />
      <input type="date" ng-model="item.date" />
      {{item.date}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a couple of issues in your code. First, when initializing the ng-model with the current date using Razor syntax, you should use double curly braces for data binding in AngularJS. Second, ensure that the CheckAvailability function is properly bound to some event, such as a button click. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
<div class='input-group date'>
    <input ng-model="BookedFromDate" type="text" value="{{@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}}" class="form-control BookedFDate" style="border-width: 0 0 2px 0;">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="font-icon font-icon-calend"></i>
    </span>
</div>

<button ng-click="CheckAvailability()">Check Availability</button>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('YourController', function($scope) {
    $scope.CheckAvailability = function () {
        alert("Hello, " + $scope.BookedFromDate);
    };
});
```

Make sure that you have included AngularJS in your project and that the controller is associated with the relevant part of your HTML. Also, ensure that the ng-click directive or some other event binding is correctly set up to trigger the CheckAvailability function.