# AngularJS Time in ng-model value not pass to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i click CheckTime button Time value doesnot pass to controller

```html
<div class='input-group date datetimepicker-2'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="FromTime" ng-init="FromTime = (date: 'hh:mm:ss')" ng-model="FromTime" placeholder="From Time" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="font-icon font-icon-clock"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```js
$scope.CheckTime = function () {
    alert("Time, " + $scope.FromTime);
};
```

Comment: Where is your "CheckTime button"? Does the alert display at all? What does it say if so?

Comment: <`a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" ng-click="CheckTime()">Check Availability</a>`

Comment: @UncleDave updated code

Comment: And my other question about whether the alert displays or not? What happens when you click the button? Are there any errors in your browser's JS console?

Comment: null value @UncleDave

Comment: What is this - `ng-init="FromTime = (date: 'hh:mm:ss')"` - supposed to do?

Comment: Fair point, that syntax is not correct. If it's meant to be an object it should be `FromTime = {date: 'hh:mm:ss'}`

Comment: it was supposed to be a filter `ng-init="FromTime = (FromTime | date: 'hh:mm:ss')"` (but only if `FromTime` is already populated with Date)

Comment: Didn't you just answer almost this same question from the same person 20 minutes ago?

Comment: The example provided by @Aleksey Solovey in your previous question answers your question, you just implemented it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*ng-init="FromTime = (date: 'hh:mm:ss')"*
is not the correct way to assign value to FromTime.
If you want to initialize FromTime with specific date then take a variable and assign it a date and then use it in **ng-init**.

```
<div class='input-group date datetimepicker-2'>
   <input type='text' class="form-control" name="FromTime" ng-init="FromTime = myDate" ng-model="FromTime" placeholder="From Time" />
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="font-icon font-icon-clock"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

In Controller,

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();
$scope.FromTime =null;
```

Comment: i need to get time value only

Comment: Sorry, didnt understand, what so you mean by time value. This will get you time value in alert box.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nJkMed  see this image

Comment: I need to pass time value only

Comment: There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. You should use Components or Controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)